# Firefox table border inconsistency - but not when inspector open

Tags: css, firefox, border

What does it mean when the tables are displayed incorrectly until I bring up the inspector, and then everything magically displays correctly?

I have a table to display, and I want borders around cells.  Some of the cells simply do not display borders consistently.   If I *refresh* the page, cells will be haphazardly outlined.  If I then choose the `Developer>Inspector` option, then all the cells instantly become correctly displayed.  Also, if I resize the browser, the table will display correctly.  When I display the same page in Chrome the cells are always outlined.  I think the real clue is that opening the inspector causes the table to display correctly ... what is the inspector doing?  I am using version 53.0.2 of Mozilla.

Here is the table styles:

```
<style>
.statusTable {
    width:100%;
}
.specialRow td {
    padding:3px;
    padding-top:20px;
    background-color:#EEE;
}
.outlinedRow td {
    padding:3px;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:grey;
}
.statusTable tr th{
    padding:3px;
}
</style>
```

There are two styles of rows, either 'specialRow' or 'outlinedRow'.  When the page is *refreshed* I get this:

[image]

But if I start the inspector, the display is corrected:

[image]

Any ideas of what I should look for?

## Edit 1

This is definitely NOT related to zoom.  I see the same problem at any level of zoom.  Refresh paints a haphazard grid at 100% scale, and the grid stays haphazard when I zoom in and zoom out.  Sometimes, when zooming additional parts of the grid will disappear.

I has tested with `border-collapse: separate`  `border-collapse: initial` and also `border-collapse: collapse` and the problem happens in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the "tbody" tags were not matched.   I had an opening `<tbody>` and another at the end of the block -- I did not have the slash.  It is not surprising that causes a lot of problems with layout.  However, strange thing is that bringing up inspector apparently goes and checks the validity of the HTML at that point in time, correcting the problem without any indication.  Chrome seems to correct on the initial page load.

Fixed the tbody end tag and everything works correctly.

Note: I did notice a dependency on bootstrap.  If I removed the bootstrap CSS files, the entire layout was broken, but the table borders were correct.  I tried tags other than tbody and did not have this problem.  So there is some indeterminate connection between unbalanced tbody and boostrap and borders, but I don't have time to find any more details.